# How to export code into runnable JAR within eclipse/lib GDX?

Tags: eclipse, libgdx

I made a game using the lib GDX library in Eclipse, and for the past hour or so I've been trying to export it into a working runnable JAR file.

At first I was getting a bunch of errors about using multiple files (images and sounds in the assets folder) but I rearranged the build configuration and I fixed that (hopefully not messing anything up).

Originally the JAR wouldn't even run but now it will run the title screen but will crash if I try to do anything.

This is my first time packaging with Eclipse, GDX and in general so I don't really know which factor is the issues.

Comment: We need the crash stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

typically, you can run gradle desktop:dist task which produce a runnable jar of your game. You can find the produced jar in the desktop/build/libs folder.